# GLSL compile fails on a mat4x3 vec4 multiplication

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a GLSL shader that works fine, until I add the following lines to it.

```
"vec4 coord = texture2D(Coordinates,gl_TexCoord[0].st);"
"mat4x3 theMatrix;"
"theMatrix[1][1] = 1.0;"
"vec3 CampProj = theMatrix * coord;"
```

when I check the error log I am told:

```
"ERROR: 0:2: '=' :  cannot convert from '4-component vector of float' to '3-component vector of float'\n\n"
```

if I make CampProject a vec4 this compiles fine, but I am very confused as to how a 4 column, 3 row matrix multiplied by a 4 component vector is gonna result in a 4 component vector.

is this a bug, or is it possible that the 4x3 matrix is really just a 4x4 under the hood with a 0,0,0,1 final row? if not can someone explain to me why the compiler is insisting on returning a vec4?

I'm using C++ via VSExpress 2013, win7, Mobile Intel® 4 Series Express Chipset Family

UPDATE:

Reto's answer is what I expect to be the case. That it is a bug in the compilation. Both because that's the only thing that makes sense in a LA context and because the LA definition is what the GLSL documentation references for matrix/matrix and matrix / vec multiplication; however, even after updating my video chipset drivers the compilation is showing me the same behavior. could one other person confirm that behavior Reto describes?

@Reto if nobody has confirmed by 12-05-14 I'll accept your answer as correct as it seems the only real logical possibility.

Comment: Are you sure there are no implicit conversions from vec4 to vec3 going on? Since multypling a 4x3 matrix by a vec3 makes sense, but not 4x3 matrix by vec4. Maybe the last 'w' coordinate of `coord` is simply being discarded for the multiplication? Check
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations

Comment: @vmg: It's very likely that the dimensions are magically expanded to to 4x4 and the new row is assigned (0,0,0,1). Incidentally, this should not work at all in a standard compliant GLSL implementation - this is a 4x3 matrix * a 1x4 column-vector. There's no way to satisfy this without lopping off the 4th row of the `vec4` or adding an extra row to the 4x3 matrix (there's no implicit conversion from `mat4x3` to `mat4` or `vec4` to `vec3` defined by GLSL, so whatever is happening is non-standard AFAIK).

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying; It's precisely that 'dropping off the 4th row of the vec' I was trying to describe.

Comment: GLSL uses a Column Major approach so a 4x3 matrix times a 4 row vector is well defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a bug in your GLSL compiler. This should compile successfully:

```
mat4x3 mat;
vec3 res = mat * vec4(1.0);
```

and this should give an error:

```
mat4x3 mat;
vec4 res = mat * vec4(1.0);
```

I tested this on 3 configurations, and all of them confirmed this behavior:

- Windows 8.1 with Intel HD Graphics 4600.
- Windows 8.1 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M.
- Mac OS Yosemite with Intel Iris Pro.

This also matches my understanding of the specs. In the GLSL 3.30 spec document, `mat4x3` is described as:

> a floating-point matrix with 4 columns and 3 rows

and multiplication is defined by (emphasis added):

> The operator is multiply (*), where both operands are matrices or one operand is a vector and the other a matrix.  A right vector operand is treated as a column vector and a left vector operand as a row vector.  In all these cases, it is required that **the number of columns of the left operand is equal to the number of rows of the right operand**.  Then, the multiply (*) operation does a linear algebraic multiply, **yielding an object that has the same number of rows as the left operand** and the same number of columns as the right operand.

In this example, the "number of columns of the left operand" is 4, which means that the vector needs to have 4 "rows", which is a column vector with 4 elements. Then, since the left operand has 3 rows,  the resulting vector has 3 "rows", which is a column vector with 3 elements.

It's also the only thing that makes sense based on standard linear algebra.

Comment: I'm upvoting this for now. check the Update above RE: acceptance.

Comment: I have now confirmed this on a new system Windows 7, nVidia GTX745

Answer (score -2):

That's because your component count of both your vec4 and your mat4x3 is four. You cannot expect to recieve a vec3 out of that multiplication.

Why don't you just use homogeneous matrix and a vec4? You'll get a vec4, and if you really must, can convert it to a vec3 by doing

```
 vec3.xyz
```

Hope this helps, my first answer!

Comment: a 4 column 3 row matrix multiplied by a 4 row vector cannot produce a 4 component vector by an Linear Algebra definition I am aware of.